# UNIX shell script to call python

Tags: python, unix, loops

I have a python script that runs on three files in the following way
align.py *.wav *.txt *.TextGrid
However, I have a directory full of files that I want to loop through. The original author suggests creating a shell script to loop through the files. 
The tricky part about the loop is that I need to match three files at a time with three different extensions for the script to run correctly. 
Can anyone help me figure out how to create a shell script to loop through a directory of files, match three of them according to name (with three different extensions) and run the python script on each triplet?
Thanks!

Comment: If there will be a wave and txt file for every TextGrid file, then I would just alter the python script to infer the names of those two, and only pass it the *.TextGrid list. Is it feasible for you to change the python script?

Comment: Please add some example files and how you'd want them to be processed. Your question doesn't sufficiently describe what you're looking for.

Comment: You don't need shell scripting at all; Python is able to look through directories itself..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using bash, here is a one-liner:

```
for f in *.wav; do align.py $f ${f%\.*}.txt ${f%\.*}.TextGrid; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to list only the `wav` files, then construct the `subprocess.Popen` call like so:

```
import glob
import os
import subprocess

for wav_name in glob.glob('*.wav'):
    basename,ext = os.path.splitext(wav_name)
    txt_name=basename+'.txt'
    grid_name=basename+'.TextGrid'
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['align.py',wav_name,txt_name,grid_name])
    proc.communicate()
```